# Проблема с cURL на локалхосте

Tags: curl, php, вконтакте

Имеется скрипт, который обращается к ВКонтакте API и публикует запись на стене.

```
  <?php

   $token='f99ddc0df194c127f194c127caf1bd79ebff194f191e127685549d79335a4c5';         //Токен доступа
   $owner_id='-33539970';//Идентификатор группы

 function postMessage($message) {

    global $token, $owner_id;
    $link = 'http://hashcode.ru';
    $request = "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post";
    $params = array(
            'owner_id'     => $owner_id,
            'message'      => $message,
            'attachments'  => $link,
            'access_token' => $token);

    $result = callMethod($request, $params);
    echo $result;

 }

 function callMethod($request, $params) {

    $c=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($c);
    if($result === false)   {
        $result = curl_error($c);
    }
    curl_close($c);

    return $result;
 }

     postMessage(Hi);
```

Когда я заливаю его на сервер, то всё отлично работает. В случае если запускаю его с локалхоста, то **curl_error** возвращает **Couldn't resolve host 'api.vk.com'**. Раньше всё отлично работало и с локалхоста, но после того как я установил wifi роутер начались подобные проблемы. Ещё более странно то, что из bash curl отлично работает. Ощущение что обёртки для libcurl используют разные методы ресолва. Даже не знаю куда мне копать и где что править.

Comment: По-видимому, с локалхоста заросы не доходят до vk, порпобуйте проверить другие сайты на предмет дохода запросов.

Comment: Да, вы правы. До гуглкарт запросы также не доходят... Сейчас буду ковырять настройки cURL.

Comment: Понял что изменилось - поставил wi-fi роутер. Но это уже не сюда вопрос.

Comment: Мне это показалось странным, но с форума руткод меня послали сюда.